# Presto connection behind a proxy with authentication

Tags: java, proxy, presto

I'm trying to use the JDBC driver to get connected to presto, but when I run the process I get:

`Error Cause java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy`

I see in the documentation we can pass the property **httpProxy** but no how to pass authentication to it.

I'm using this version: **0.239.1**

```
String url = "jdbc:presto://MY-SERVER:PORT/dal_hms_prod/default?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&SSL=true";
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("httpProxy", "PROXY_SERVER:PORT");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
log.info("Connection stablished "+connection.getSchema());
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
String sql = "select test from usersource.usersource_flat limit 1;";
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Hope someone can give me some insights. Thanks.

Comment: Pull request is already open on the GitHub repository https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/15160